# Cant run executable after running the pyinstaller successfully

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[output after double clicking the exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBCld.png)

made a tic tac toe game with a gui that runs through pyton but get an error when I run it through the exe made with pyinstaller
command used in powershell to make the exe:
`pyinstaller.exe --onefile tic.py`

Comment: as you can see, the error occurs when initializing the font. pyinstaller can't find it, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751446/error-with-fonts-when-using-pyinstaller-to-convert-a-pygame-app-to-executable) for a possible fix

Comment: yes, it was a font issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, changed the code from `pg.font.Font(None, 30)` to `pg.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)`